# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $C<1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le C$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that this $f$ has a unique fixed point such that $f(x_0)=x_0$ and if $f(0)>0$ then $x_0>0$?

I think this calls for an application of Mean Value Theorem but I don't see how to begin.

Comment: Are you asking a different question in the title and the body?

Comment: @Seth yes fixed!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is a [contraction mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem)

Comment: Perhaps a cannon to kill a mosquito?

Comment: Looks just about right to me

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$. We have $g'(x)=f'(x)-1<=C-1=k<0$. So that if $x_1>x_2$, we have $g(x_1)-g(x_2)=g'(\eta)(x_1-x_2) \le k(x_1-x_2)$.

Then when $x > 0$, $g(x) \le g(0)+kx$, so when $x$ is sufficiently big, $g(x)$ is negative; While when $0 > x$, $g(0)-g(x)\le k(0-x)\Rightarrow g(0) +kx \le g(x)$ so when $x$ is sufficiently small, $g(x)$ is positive.

As $g(x)$ is continuous, it must achieve $0$ somewhere. As it's monotonic, it achieves $0$ only once. If $f(0) > 0$, we have $g(0) > 0$, and $x_0$ must be between $0$ (which makes $g(x)$ positive), and $+\infty$ (which makes $g(x)$ negative.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $g(x) = x - f(x)$. Then $g'(x) = 1 - f'(x) \geq 1 - C$. 
Note $1 - C$ is positive. So by the mean value theorem
$$g(x) - g(0) > (1 - C)x$$
So if $g(0)$ is negative, if $x$ is large enough $g(x) > 0$. Hence by the intermediate value theorem some positive $y$ in between satisfies $g(y) = 0$, which is the same as $f(y) = y$. If $g(0)$ is positive, similarly use that for $x < 0$ one has
$$g(0) - g(x) > (1- C)(-x)$$
Then for $x$ negative enough one will similarly have $ g(x) < 0$ and the intermediate value theorem can be similarly used to say that $f(y) = y$ for some $y < 0$.

Uniqueness in both cases follows from the fact that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing.